# invoking an outer function inside my function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Why when I call an outer function `refreshBox()` inside my function `checkOnclick` it isn't invoked, but when invoke it in a new line it works?

```
function checkOnclick(unTasksBox, fnTasksBox, localUnTasks, localFnTasks) {
    unTasksBox.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
        var target = e.target;
        
        if (target.parentElement.classList.contains("fir-icon-task")) {

            if (unTasksBox == allUnFinishedBox) {
                mydayTasks.forEach(task => {
                    if (task.querySelector('.myday-parg').innerHTML == 
                        target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.innerHTML) {
                        task.querySelector('.fir-icon-task i').click();
                    }
                });
                // here it doesn't work
                refreshBox(allUnFnTasksBox, allFnTasksBox, 1201, 1401);
           }
     })
}
checkOnclick(unfinishedTasks, finishedTasks, 'numOfTasks', "numOfFinishedTasks");

function refreshBox(unBox, fnBox, num1, num2) {
    var unArr = [],
        fnArr = [];

    function refresh(tasksBox, arr, addedNum) {
        tasksBox.forEach(elem => {
            arr.push(elem)
        });

        arr.forEach(elem => {
            elem.setAttribute("data-number", arr.indexOf(elem) + addedNum);
        })
    }
    refresh(unBox, unArr, num1);
    refresh(fnBox, fnArr, num2);
}
// here it works
refreshBox(allUnFnTasksBox, allFnTasksBox, 1201, 1401);
```

**Note:** I want to apply `refreshBox()`on elements that made by the user and not present in the original document.

Comment: Try moving `refreshBox` above `checkOnclick`?

Comment: Have you confirmed that `refreshBox` is actually being called when the click listener is invoked?

Comment: #terrymorse yes `refreshBox` is working but the `forEach` is not working! I didn't see like this before

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "not working"? Please include the error that you're getting.

Comment: Shirhan Kumar Padhy I mean that `forEach` inside the function `refreshBox` is not working and nothing happens. there is no error in the page